# What does this operator mean?

Tags: c, mips

I am going through a C code that I did in one of my assembly MIPS classes and I dont know what one of the operators mean:

```
if (TOKEN[0] <> symTab[$a0])
```

Thats the line. what does the `<>` mean?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to mean `distinct`, but is not legal C as far as I know... Neither is `$a0`.

Comment: That's not C code, I can tell you that much. `<>` usually means "not equal".

Comment: we were going over a MIPS code and writing the pseudo code in C so we were going back and forth between the two codes. but thank you

Comment: $a0 is not c neither. And since this seems to me a string comparison (token? symbol table?) this is absolutely not c, since c don't allows direct string comparison.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like "not equal to" was intended.

The correct operator in standard C is `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

That code is not C and in fact it's a Pascal like syntax. The use of the NOT EQUALS operator <> and the hex literal prefix $ indicate that.

Comment: Wikipedia calls it BASIC-like, which I think is more appropriate since BASIC was before Pascal.

Comment: @Aaron BASIC does not use $ as hex literal prefix. So no, this is not BASIC.

Comment: Oops thought that was a string variable name, but that was $ as a suffix in BASIC.  Apologies.

Comment: @Aaron As someone who has spent the past 20 years writing Pascal, I recognise it when I see it!!

Answer (score 0):

It's another way of representing **IS NOT** or **NOT EQUAL**. The valid operator is `!=` in C.

You can use `<>` in SQL. I posted so late because I couldn't remember the language that used it.

EDIT: Actually it was Pascal as well that I was thinking of that also uses `<>`, as David mentions.